# Laravel seeding mass-assignment, can't see where I'm going wrong

Tags: laravel, eloquent, mass-assignment

In my seeder:

```
    $model->create(array(
        'name' => 'Test name'
    ));
```

In my model:

```
class Model extends Content {
        protected $fillable = array('name');
}
```

But when I run the create method, the record just gets created in the database with NULL in the name field.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this.

Model was extending Content which extends Eloquent.

I was overriding the constructor in Content, and not passing the $attributes array to the Eloquent constructor. I needed to change this:

```
class Content extends Eloquent {
    public function __construct() {
        ...
        parent::__construct();
    }
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
class Content extends Eloquent {
public function __construct($attributes = array()) {
        ...
        parent::__construct($attributes);
}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your seed you will need to "unguard" Eloquent.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/736#issuecomment-15597996

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on your model instead:

```
class Model extends Content {
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

to remove the un-necessary code.

Or on your seeder try:

```
Model::create(['name' => 'foobar']);
```

Or add this on your seeder:

```
Eloquent::unguard();
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this but same thing is happening. Updated my question. Any ideas?

Comment: @tparson can you give more code and show what the actual class is? maybe you are working with different models? Also updated my answer.

Comment: Turns out Model extends Content which extends Eloquent and wasn't passing arguments to the Eloquent constructor properly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are specifing both the fillable and the guarded properties.
You only need one of them!

Comment: Thanks, tried this but same thing is happening. Updated my question. Any ideas?

Comment: do you run this command? `php artisan db:seed` if so check the app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder and tell us if it looks like this https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php

Comment: in addition you are extending a Content class not Eloquent, Content extends Eloquent?

Comment: Yep I run that command and yes the master seeder looks like that. Content does extend Eloquent, forgot to mention.

Comment: Ah! The Content model wasn't passing the proper arguments to the Eloquent constructor method, that fixed it. Thanks! :)

Comment: glad you find the problem^